# Webcam's LED indicator turns on by itself. Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: webcam

I don't use any applications could use camera. I have fresh, recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 and only two programms I've installed were Chrome and Geany. I also ran two commands in terminal with granting root access:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip

sudo pip3 install virtualenv
```

Also I tried this command:

```
sudo lsof /dev/video*
[sudo] password for nick_name: 
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
```

But I can't to figure out what does this output means.

it's pretty annoying and I suspice that somebody watching me. Am I paranoid?

Comment: high chances it's a linux/ubuntu side issue and You probably aren't paranoid "just in case if...", these days anything possible even in linux world ;-)

Comment: How do you know the webcam is turned on?

Comment: Please provide info on how you decided cams are turned on. The light activating during startup is NOT proof; that is your -hardware- confirming a driver is loaded. Nothing more.

Comment: The light activates not during startup but in the middle of work. And it's not disappeared after laptop go into sleep mode.

Answer (score 1):

Only solution that works for me is to install some app for webcam, i installed app called "Cheese". Than when LED indicator is on just open Cheese app and close it. LED indicator should go off as soon as you close Cheese app. I know it is not the best solution but it will do the job for now.